# ImportError: unable to find classes defined in imported module

Tags: python-3.6, python-import, importerror

I have a flask application that I'm trying to test but am having an import error that is killing me slowly.  It's the classic 'worked an hour ago, now it's not'.

My package structure is like this:

```
__init__.py
main.py
  /tasks
    email_utils.py
    send_api.py
    __init__.py
```

send_api.py contains a class called SendEmail, which I am trying to import from main.py to add as a resource, like this:

```
from tasks.send_api import SendEmail
```

which causes an ImportError.  I've also tried

```
from tasks import send_api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(send_api.SendEmail, '/send')
```

but the last line throws an AttributeError, saying SendEmail is not an attribute of send_api.  If I drop a breakpoint in after just importing send_api and inspect it using dir(send_api) the class name does not show up in the attributes, nor do any other global vars / classes except for some of the imports.  It's also weird to me that PyCharm seems to recognize SendEmail as a class of send_api and doesn't give me any warnings.

send_api.py is structured like this

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_restful import abort as fr_abort
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseResponse as Response

from customexceptions import MissingEnvironmentVariables
from tasks import email_utils

class SendEmail(Resource):
    #class logic here
```

If I just import send_api from tasks in main.py and dir(send_api)the only meaningful results I get are MissingEnvironmentVariables, Resource, Response, and fr_abort (all the things imported in send_api.py except for email_utils, which seems like it should show up.  Even email_utils doesn't seem to get picked up.

I've been going at this for a while now and really  just don't have a clue how to fix this.  It also seems odd to me that to import email_utils.py from send_api.py I have to do

```
from tasks import email_utils
```

as

```
import email_utils
```

or

```
import .email_utils
```

don't seem to work either.

Sorry for the lengthy post, please let me know if there's something I'm obviously doing wrong or point me to a related question that would help.

Comment: So, `main.py` is not part of your package, right? Did you try removing `__init__.py` from the root?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but it seems to have fixed my issue.  I guess I misunderstood package structures with __init__.py files and need to do some reading.  thank you much, I had worked around it through finding the project root at runtime and adding the subpackages to the PATH, but I hate doing it that way.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.